# Reputation drop by 2 without event

Tags: support, reputation

I experienced a drop by 2 in my reputation without anything displayed in my event history.
Why was that?

**EDIT**
A deletion of an answer that I accepted would do, but shouldn't I see a "user removed" then?

Comment: You "expected" ... or you "experienced"? (I can never anticipate upswings or down-swings in my reputation ... )

Comment: experienced, sorry, I mixed up words. I just wondered, I don't worry.

Comment: no problem - I do that all the time :)

Comment: Undeletion of an old downvote?

Comment: Undeletion of one of my deleted downvoted answers? By whom?

Comment: Only the database knows...

Comment: @OldJohn My meta account should soon experience an expected jump by 5.

Comment: @AsafKaragila a deletion of a question where my answer was accepted :(and had 0 votes ;) would do...

Comment: Isn't that **15** points?

Comment: ah right, so it must have been an answer that I accepted.

Comment: Really? Users cannot on their own initiative delete answers that someone else has accepted. That requires moderator intervention, and is something that most (if not all) of our current moderators are unwilling to do.

Comment: I am leaning more toward you accidentally unaccepting an answer, or like Asaf said, some answers that you downvoted got undeleted (possibly by the owner).